# Could $_REQUEST variables lead to code execution?

Tags: php, security, phpmailer

Hey I was wondering if there is any kind of vulnerability hidden behind the $_REQUEST variables that everyone should care about. Let's assume that we have PHPMailer library and we call mail.php through an html form tag:

```
    ...
    //mail.php

    //send email
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
    $subject = 'mail test';
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
    $tel = $_REQUEST['tel'];
    $formcontent=" From: $name \n e-mail: $email \n Telephone: $tel \n Message: $message";

    require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    ....

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $formcontent;
    $mail->send();

    ...
```

Could actually someone forge a payload by sending some "evil" characters that would lead to any arbitrary code execution or anything similiar?

Comment: PHP will interpret everything in `$_REQUEST` as strings. You should be ok as long as you're not doing something silly like `eval` or **echoing them as raw HTML**. Always run them through an [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) (or similar) before sending them to a browser (or in this case email client)

Comment: If you are worried about the PHPMailer vulnerabilities disclosed at the beginning of the year. You are only allowing code execution if you pass user input to the setFrom method, or manipulate Sender in some other way. In addition you would have to use one of the affected MTAs, and of course a version of PHPMailer that hasn't been updated since then.

Comment: I see...it's better using an updated version of PHPMailer with $_GET and not $_REQUEST variable.

Comment: Indeed, the vulns in PHPMailer last year were entirely dependent on calling scripts trusting user-supplied input (and PHP bugs), which was well beyond PHPMailer’s remit anyway. It’s trivially easy to write an exploitable script, not quite so easy to write an unexploitable one.

Comment: Short version: using $_REQUEST is safe if you treat it as you would any other untrusted input.

Answer (score 3):

I decided to make a more detailed answer because Security is important.

`$_REQUEST` is not the problem, how someone use it is the problem. `$_REQUEST` is just the sum of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`. So the same principals apply to `$_REQUEST`.

First of all if you try to follow the principal of **"not trusting any data that come from a user"** you will figure out what to do next.

The Important part with any data no mater where it came from is that you thing about where is it going to. So if you put the data into a HTML template and do not escape the important HTML characters than this could lead to corrupt or hacked websites. The same is true if the data that goes to the database or to any other destination.

In your case you use the PHPMailer, and I do not know how much security is implement there and if PHPMailer is not doing any escaping it could be that someone add something to the mail that you do not want.

There is addition one issue with `$_REQUEST`. Because it is the sum of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`, it could be that you you do not see all data, or that you thing this is coming from your URL but is coming from a Cookie.

This is the case if e.g `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE` having the same key, than you only seeing one value depending of your configuration. This is why I prefer to use `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`, but the other principals are still valid.

Comment: Can you suggest any useful PHP methods for a better string handling in terms of security?

Comment: There are a lot of them so it real depending on the context. I would not put it here because it a little bit off-topic but if you have a concrete problem where you do not find an answer, we are glad to help. There is no **On Fits all Solution**

Comment: If one answer fitting your initial question you can mark it as accepted. If you have a new question just create one. I'm happy if you upvote my answer, no mater if its the prefered one or not, that shows me that you appreciate my work.

Comment: One additional note to an otherwise excellent answer: using `$_REQUEST` is a good way to being vulnerable to CSRF. You intend functionality to work when the request is a POST, and you have generic protection on POST requests. However, due to `$_REQUEST`, the query unintendedly works the same when GET is used - thus making the page vulnerable to CSRF.